# How to change multiple fields from an object without doing update? (because I need to use the save method, because of pre)

Tags: mongoose

Mongoose:

How to update multiple fields of the model without using update or manually setting every field?

thanks (:

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [underscore](https://npmjs.org/package/underscore):

```
var _ = require('underscore');

_.extend(doc, new_data);
doc.save(next);
```

See [API Docs](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) for more info.